# Install two versions of a certain package in anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have the following issue:

One package that I want to install through conda demands a certain version of another package. However, I want to install a newer version of the second package.

Specifically, the package `energysim 2.1.5` demands the package `fmpy 0.2.14` and when I am trying to install a newer version of `fmpy` I am getting error:

```
ERROR: energysim 2.1.5 has requirement fmpy==0.2.14, but you'll have fmpy 0.3.0 which is incompatible.
```

Is it possible something like that and how?

Comment: Say `packageA` depends on `packageB` (v.1). If I understand you want `packageB` (v.2) ?

Comment: @CutePoison Yes, exactly this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide more details; "conda demands a certain version of another package" can mean a few different things that could result in different answers.

Comment: @MattThompson I edited the post including some relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

In my answer, I am assuming the following case:

- You want to install packageA, which requires packageB==v1
- You also want to install packageB at version v2

**Your goal**: Install packageB with version v1 **and** v2 to make this possible

I don't know of any way this can be achieved. I also don't see a way that this would even technically work. Say you do `import packageB` in your code. Which version should be imported? How should python know that `import packageB` done by packageA should be v1, but `import packageB` done by you should be v2?

I see these options:

1. not using packageA, so that you can have packageB at the version you need
2. If possible, have one environment where you packageA and packageB and another with only packageB at the version you want
3. Fork packageA and create your own custom version that works with your required version of packageB

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just be able to do:

```py
conda install packageB==2.0.0
conda install packageA
```

Comment: This would work I guess if packageA has requirement packageB>=1.0, but probably not when the requirement is packageB==1.0 if I am not mistaken. It is not clear which exactly is the case from OPs post.

Comment: I agree - if the latter is the case, there's no way to overcome it (without some very tricky use of virtual-envs)

Comment: @CutePoison Yes, unfortunately, this is the case. When I am trying to install a newer version I am getting error: ERROR: energysim 2.1.5 has requirement fmpy==0.2.14, but you'll have fmpy 0.3.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: Aah.. okay. I misunderstood you then. Unfortunately I don't have a solution to that, apart from creating a virtual_env and see if that can be used to solve the issue in some way

Answer (score 1):

The package `energysim` is pinned [1] to use
`fmpy` 0.2.14 and no other versions (older or newer). It looks like this was done intentionally [2]; the maintainer may have good reasons to enforce this pin. `pip` won't let you install 0.3 because of this pin.

I would reach out to them via a GitHub issue to ask if their package is compatible with newer versions. It looks like `fmpy` 0.2.14 is about a year and a half old, for what it's worth. It may work fine with 0.3.x, but IMHO it should be tested and released before using it.

1. https://github.com/dgusain1/energysim/blob/07282257073058119664f9a5e8fd4300e138a64d/setup.py#L25-L29
2. https://github.com/dgusain1/energysim/commit/f84dad3ab913b43eea3187da54c132319c23d1a7